# Code breakpoint

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, breakpoints

Hi I have a code that when I run quits and says there is a breakpoint

```
- (void)checkCollision{
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(penny.frame, hand.frame))
    {
        [randomMain invalidate];
        [startButton setHidden:NO];

        pos= CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0);

        CGRect frame = [penny frame];
        frame.origin.x=137.0f;
        frame.origin.y=326.0;
        [penny setFrame:frame];     (the breakpoint is here)

        CGRect frame2 = [hand frame];
        frame2.origin.x=137.0f;
        frame2.origin.y=20.0;
        [hand setFrame:frame2];

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lose" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"He got the penny!"] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

any ideas?
i apologize for the sloppy format Im new to the website, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a breakpoint gets out of sync with the code presented. Try going to your breakpoint window (Command + 6 or View->Navigators->Show Breakpoint Navigator.

In that navigator, you may see active breakpoints. If you can find the errant breakpoint, delete it from the list. Otherwise, your best bet is to delete all your breakpoints.